# Doxygen base classes not resolved sometimes

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a C++ library with several source files documented with Doxygen style comments. In the library, there are three class templates (`Array`, `Vector`, `Span`) that all inherit the same base class template (`VctrBase`). I set `INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB` to `YES` in the Doxyfile.

### The problem

For two of those classes (`Array` and `Vector`), the rendered documentation shows all inherited base class member functions and the inheritance graph shows the `VctrBase` base class along with the two base classes of `VctrBase`. For one class (`Span`) however, this does not work. Especially the inheritance graph shows the base class greyed out and does not show the second inheritance layer as seen in the two other class documentations.

### My assumption

I am no doxygen expert, but my guess here is that the dependencies between multiple sourcefiles are not resolved properly. I was under the impression that the order in which source files are processed by doxygen does not matter so even if the `Span` source file should be parsed before the `VctrBase` source file things should just work from my knowledge. But I suspect that the error might originate from a misunderstanding about that on my side.

### Further information

I'm running Doxygen version 1.9.6 on a GitHub Actions Ubuntu runner.
The entire project I'm referencing above is open source and you can have a look at the sources [here](https://github.com/sonible/VCTR/tree/VCTR-86-Automatically-render-a-doxygen-docu-with-builds/include/vctr). For quicker navigation, here are direct links to

- [The Doxyfile](https://github.com/sonible/VCTR/blob/VCTR-86-Automatically-render-a-doxygen-docu-with-builds/Doxyfile)
- [The subdirectory containing the Array, Vector and Span along with their shared base class](https://github.com/sonible/VCTR/tree/VCTR-86-Automatically-render-a-doxygen-docu-with-builds/include/vctr/Containers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, file: include/vctr/Containers/Span.h branch: VCTR-86-Automatically-render-a-doxygen-docu-with-builds you have the line:

```
template <class ElementType, size_t extent = std::dynamic_extent, class StorageInfoType = StorageInfo<std::span<ElementType, extent>>>
class Span : public VctrBase<ElementType, std::span<ElementType, extent>, extent, StorageInfoType>
```

and doxygen is apparently confused by the usage of `>>>` by changing this in `> > >` so:

```
template <class ElementType, size_t extent = std::dynamic_extent, class StorageInfoType = StorageInfo<std::span<ElementType, extent> > >
class Span : public VctrBase<ElementType, std::span<ElementType, extent>, extent, StorageInfoType>
```

I think it gives the results you need.

Comment: Indeed, that solved it! I'd consider this a doxygen bug since this is valid C++ code, so I'll raise a doxygen bug report. For now I can live with adding two whitespaces to the code ;)

Comment: Indeed best to raise an issue but will be a hard issue due to the interaction with the `>>` operator.